# How to stop the spikey mess

Tags: mesh

[image]I am doing a mesh edit, when I am done in edit mode and go to object mode
my mesh badly deforms , then back to object mode and it returns to normal,
and it does the same if I try to import another object , anyone that can tell me how to fix this would be greatly appreciated .

FBX File:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jlzfRadiKp3RQBkh59MVxvUZgUvgzFPl

blend file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mdg8hQXY8JnlS4Xo7m16yT3aHqwOfb-M

[image]

Comment: maybe it has to do with the shapekeys? Perhaps share your file?

Comment: Instead of an fbx, the original .blend file would be actually way more helpful. Also, please use [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) for uploads, because questions and also answers might be totally useless once you decide to delete the files from google drive.

Comment: can do ,did not know about blender exchange but I got an error message saying it does not accept this type of file , but posted my google link no plan to remove it any time soon thanks for working the problem.

Comment: There are indeed a ton of shapekeys in your file that mess up the geometry. There is also an empty Armature modifier and a completely useless Remesh modifier in your modifier stack. Without knowing the purpose of the end result, I'd advise to get rid of the shape keys by deleting them in the Outliner, then also get rid of the useless modifiers. You are then left with the basic mesh which contains of two torsos side by side.